# Split a column into multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data={'GradeCol':['BVCS,105308.248']}

data1=DataFrame(data)
print(data1)
data1[['GradeColText','GradeColNum']] = pd.DataFrame([x for x in 
data1.GradeCol])

#data1[['GradeColText','GradeColNum']] = 
#pd.DataFrame(data1.GradeCol.values.tolist())
print(data1)
```

while splitting row into columns getting 
error
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Expected output

```
GradeColText GradeColNum

BVCS         105308.248
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ?

```
data={'GradeCol':['BVCS,105308.248']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.GradeCol.str.split(',', 1).tolist(),
                  columns=['GradeColText', 'GradeColNum'])

  GradeColText GradeColNum
0         BVCS  105308.248
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.str.rsplit(expand=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
In [429]: df[['GradeColText', 'GradeColNum']] = df['GradeCol'].str.rsplit(',', expand=True)

In [432]: df.drop(['GradeCol'], axis=1, inplace=True); df
Out[432]: 
  GradeColText GradeColNum
0         BVCS  105308.248
```

Comment: Good answer +1~

Comment: @Wen Thank you :)

Comment: I still get the same error as `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` with it